# Why is accept returned socket different from the param socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

```
int accept(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address,socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

The accept method receive a listen fd socket and return a conn fd. Of course they are different. But the two socket have the same port, why they are different?

`listen` method listen connection, if tcp 3 way handshake finished, the socket becomes acceptable. How do the listen socket transfer tcp connection to the new conn fd socket during `accept`?

Answer (score 7):

> But the two socket have the same port, why they are different?

Because otherwise you could never have more than one simultaneous client. The accepted socket also has a peer IP address and port, which the listening socket doesn't have.

> How do the listen socket transfer tcp connection the new conn fd socket during accept?

It doesn't 'transfer' anything. `accept()` creates a new socket with the connection details.

Comment: It doesn't 'transfer' anything. It creates a new socket with the connection details. It means: accept creates a new socket with the connection details and the listen fd would point to the connection details?

Comment: It creates a new socket with the connection details. Which is exactly what I said. No 'means' about it. The part starting 'and the listen FD' doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Then the connection details is created in `listen` or in `accept`?

Comment: Neither. They are created by the three-way handshake, as you said in your question, and placed on the backlog queue. Creating them in `listen()` doesn't begin to make sense. There is no connection yet. Strange question.

Comment: Got it. The question is in my understanding context but is strange in truth.

Comment: A TCP socket is associated with both local IP/Port and peer IP/Port. A listening socket has no peer IP/Port, just the local IP/Port. `listen()` opens a backlog queue to perform 3-way handshakes with incoming TCP clients on the local IP/Port. `accept()` takes a listening socket to know which queue to pull a connected TCP client from, then returns a new socket that has the listening IP/Port and client IP/Port associated with it. Any packets sent using the accepted socket go to the client IP/Port, and any packets received with the two IP/Port pairs on them are readable using the accepted socket